# Is there a Python equivalent to the Perl "/x" modifier for regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, perl

Perl makes it easy to construct [readable regular expressions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194999/24321) using the `/x` modifier. This modifier allows to write regular expression strings and ignore all whitespaces in these strings. In other words, logical parts of the regular expression can be separated by whitespace or even carriage returns, allowing great readability. In Python, the only way I see of doing this is to construct such regular expression string, remove whitespace from it in an intermediate step, and then use the resulting string for matching. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know of any normal engine that doesn't have the expanded modifier. All things considered you need a regex formatting program that does compression/expansion automatically. This is a good one http://www.regexformat.com. They are coming out with version 5 next week which has inline testing and incredible macro capability.

Comment: Just a note that any engine that supports modifiers usually support them `'inline'`, so for expanded mode the first char's of the regex string would be  the  modifier construct `"(?x)  .."`. Modifiers can be anywhere. Read about modifiers, save your brain.

Comment: @sln Thanks for the comment. I'm already starting to see what you mean.

Comment: @sln Python requires that `(?x)` is inserted at the start (excepting whitespace). If you insert it later on the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, by setting the [`re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` flag](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.X):

> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer. Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class, or when preceded by an unescaped backslash, or within tokens like `*?`, `(?:` or `(?P<...>`. When a line contains a `#` that is not in a character class and is not preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such `#` through the end of the line are ignored.
>
> That means that the two following regular expression objects that match a decimal number are functionally equal:
>
> ```
> a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
>                    \.    # the decimal point
>                    \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
> b = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
> ```

This is pretty much exactly like the `/x` Perl flag.

You can control the same flag in a subsection of your pattern within the `(?x:...)` (enable) and `(?-x:...)` (disable) groupings.

Comment: I'd also point out that at least for the example from the docs, you could just make each line an independent string, and they'd be concatenated together, allowing you to use standard Python comments, which would be arguably more obvious to read.

Comment: @SilasRay: I disagree; you'd have to quote each snippet you wanted to put whitespace around. Note that there is a space between `\d` and `+` for example.

Comment: Hence why I said "arguably".  ;)  Personally, I find it clearer, but that may be because I generally work with editors that have color code formatting, so the strings and comments stick out as separate more clearly to me if they are true Python comments/strings.

Answer (score 3):

To add, inline modifiers can be placed within a regular expression to enforce relevant matching behavior on the given expression. In Python the inline modifiers apply to the entire regular expression, and do not support **inline negate** modifiers such as `(?-ismx)`

```
pattern = re.compile(r'''
                       (?x) 
                        \d+ (?# Some numbers)
                        \s+ (?# Whitespace)
                        \d+ (?# More numbers)
                      ''');
```

The way around that would be to import Python's **regex** module in which the inline modifiers apply to the end of the group or pattern, and they can be turned on or off.

```
import regex
pattern = regex.compile(r'(?x)  \d+  (?-x)[a-z]+(?x)   \d+', regex.V1)
```

Comment: Given the `re.compile()` usage, does the engine see a bunch of literal whitespace before that `(?x)` or does it retroactively affect the entire regex?